# How to use a variable globally without declaring it as a global?

Tags: c++, variables

I have a switch statement like this

```
switch(option)
{
case 1:
{
    int randomVariable;
}
case 2:
{

}
case 3:
{
\\ I want to use randomVariable here but it is not letting me since it is not in the same scope
}

}
}
```

Any Ideas on how to solve this issue? Please note that `randomVariable` must be declared under `case 1:` and `randomVariable` is an array. Please try to stick to std libraries and please please please do not use vectors as this is for a project and vectors are not at all discussed in this class.

Comment: Just declare the variable right above the `switch` statement.

Comment: @Aiias I forgot to mention, the randomVariable must be declared in `case 1:` scope

Comment: And why MUST it be declared in case 1? Maybe rather it must be initialized in case 1?

Comment: @duDE yes it must be declared inside `case 1:` as this is the option that creates the array. So are you saying that I can declare the variable as randomVariable as a global and later I can declare the length of the array in `case 1:`?

Comment: @user2086751 - You can with pointers. See [dynamic memory](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) documentation.

Comment: @Aiias `randomVariable` will be a static array the length of which will be determined by a user input, does that change your answer?

Comment: @user2086751 - Nope. However, every time you go through `case 1`, you're going to overwrite the existing value.

Comment: "vectors are not at all discussed in this class" - how it can be called a C++ class is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:

After your comments, for your use case, you probably want something like this:

```
int * myArr = 0;
int myArrSize = 10;

switch (option) {
  case 1:
    if (myArr != 0) {
      // Clean up memory if we are re-initializing
      delete [] myArr;
    }
    myArr = new int[myArrSize];
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
  case 3:
    int test = myArr[1];
    break;
}

// Clean up memory when we are done with the array
delete [] myArr;
```

Comment: Nope. This is C++, he definitely doesn't want to end up with this ugly memory management in this ghastly C-style code.

Comment: How could `myArr` ever be nonzero in case 1?

Comment: Variable length arrays are not allowed in C++.  `myArrSize` must be a const expression if you want to use it as the size of an array.

Comment: This compiles for me using GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: That's either because you are compiling it as C instead of C++, or you didn't disable non-standard extensions with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: I'll revert back to my response using dynamic memory.

Comment: @user2086751: I added a simple example in my answer as well. Look at it and decide whether you want to use `new[]` and `delete[]` and hope that the memory is always freed and there are no memory leaks, or you want to use great feature that C++ provides to take care of this for you.

Answer (score 3):

The region in which you are able to access a variable is called its ***scope***. For local non-static variables the boundaries of this scope are defined with curly braces (`{` ... `}`), so:

```
{
    ...
    int a = 0;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            int b;
            a = 2;
        } // <-- the scope of b ends here
        ...
    }
} // <-- the scope of a ends here
```

> *Please note that `randomVariable` must be declared inside of `case 1:` as this is the option that creates the array*

Since you are programming in C++, instead of C-style array use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), which is the container holding elements within the continuous block of memory just like an array, but it can change in size:

```
#include <vector>
...
{
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            int size;
            // value retrieved in run-time is assigned into size here
            myVector.resize(size, 0);
        }
        case 2:
        {
            // you can use your vector here:
            if (myVector.size() > 3)
                myVector[2] = 7;
        }
        ...
    }
} // <-- end of myVector's scope
```

in this example [`myVector.resize(size, 0);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) resizes the memory internally used by vector so that it's big enough to hold `size` elements and if its size has been increased it also inserts new elements to this memory and initializes them to `0`. What is important here is that `myVector` is an object with automatic storage duration, which means that when the execution goes out of the scope where it has been defined, the memory is cleaned up automatically. This saves you from the ugly memory management that you would have to take care of in case you use dynamically allocated C-style array.

Comment: I really wish I could have used vectors, but as I said, this is for a class project and in this class we wont talk about vectors at all :(

Answer (score 1):

With your restriction that it has to be initialized in case 1, then just make the variable a pointer and use `variable = new something();` in case 1.

By the way, this scope has nothing to do with "global".

Comment: randomVariable will be a static array with the length being determined by a user input, would declaring it as a pointer be appropriate?

Comment: I believe arrays of dynamic length (like so: `int variable[nonConstantSizeSpecifier];`) are not supported by all compilers, so you should use `new` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A variable's scope is only within the block it is defined, so no it is not possible to define the variable in one scope i.e. within `case 1:` and access it outside the scope, unless you intend to combine the cases for 1 and 3 together without an explicit block `{ ... }`.

Define the `randomVariable` in a scope visible throughout the switch statement, so that any case can access this variable.

```
{
    int randomVariable;
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            {

            }
        case 2:
            {

            }
        case 3:
            {
                \\ I want to use randomVariable here but it is not letting me since it is not in the same scope
            }

    }
}
```

The scope above the switch could be a function, or another block depending on your code.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the randomVariable must be declared in `case 1:` scope

Answer (score 0):

here you go...

- Make a new class(say for ex. superClass).
- Create a stub of property field named randomVariable with getter & setter method.
- make that property as static. (so that it's value can be used Globally same, even with different object differences).
- Inherit this class in the class where you put your switch statements.
- Now you can initialize & use randomvariable wherever you want by setting it's new or old value.

Hope this will help..!!!